# Gradle - Run Existing Task Before Sub Task

Tags: java, gradle

I'm using [researchgate's gradle release plugin](https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release) to perform version management and `maven-publish` plugin to upload generated artifact to a private maven repository. When I run gradle-release-plugin's release task it runs following sub-tasks (*user-dao-plugin* is my dummy project's name) -

```
:user-dao-plugin:createScmAdapter
:user-dao-plugin:initScmAdapter
:user-dao-plugin:checkCommitNeeded
:user-dao-plugin:checkUpdateNeeded
:user-dao-plugin:unSnapshotVersion
:user-dao-plugin:confirmReleaseVersion
:user-dao-plugin:checkSnapshotDependencies
:user-dao-plugin:runBuildTasks
:user-dao-plugin:user-dao-plugin:beforeReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:user-dao-plugin:user-dao-plugin:compileJava
:user-dao-plugin:user-dao-plugin:processResources
:user-dao-plugin:user-dao-plugin:classes
:user-dao-plugin:user-dao-plugin:findMainClass
:user-dao-plugin:user-dao-plugin:jar
:user-dao-plugin:user-dao-plugin:bootRepackage
:user-dao-plugin:user-dao-plugin:assemble
:user-dao-plugin:user-dao-plugin:compileTestJava
:user-dao-plugin:user-dao-plugin:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
:user-dao-plugin:user-dao-plugin:testClasses
:user-dao-plugin:user-dao-plugin:test
2017-08-02 20:48:47.430  INFO 27013 --- [       Thread-5] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@649f626d: startup date [Wed Aug 02 20:48:46 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
:user-dao-plugin:user-dao-plugin:check
:user-dao-plugin:user-dao-plugin:build
:user-dao-plugin:user-dao-plugin:afterReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:user-dao-plugin:preTagCommit
:user-dao-plugin:createReleaseTag
:user-dao-plugin:updateVersion
:user-dao-plugin:commitNewVersion
```

I want to run maven-publish's `publish` task right after `check` sub-task. I'm struggling on finding a way to do this.

I tried setting task dependencies but I'm not getting a reference to the `check` sub-task.

How can I go about achieving this?

Comment: It's easily doable, but the question is how exactly you want it done. Do you always want to run `publish` if `check` was run? Do you only want to run `publish` manually? Do you want `publish` to be run if some other task was triggered like `release`? Does `publish` depend on the results of `check` or why do you need to run it after that one?

Comment: @Vampire I'd like to run publish after `check` to make the release task also install artifact on repo. `check` task is right before the task which updates the project version ans is after all build and test tasks, that is why I'm doing it before it. I'd also like to be able to run `publish` independently of `release`.

Comment: But wouldn't the correct setup be `publish` depends on `build` (which also is after `check`) and `release` depends on `publish`? So if you run `release` it is automatically published and if you run `publish` it also works fine and makes sure the project is built first?

Comment: @Vampire irrespective of the order, can you tell how to run `publish` after any `release` sub task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Vampire irrespective of the order, can you tell how to run `publish` after any `release` sub task?

Based on your last comment, what you are after is

```
release.finalizedBy publish
```

Or maybe (your usage of sub task is confusing, because there is nothing called sub task in Gradle.)

```
subprojects { release.finalizedBy publish }
```

And you might also need

```
publish.dependsOn build
```

or

```
subprojects { publish.dependsOn build }
```

so that `build` is run always before `publish` eben if you it without `release`.